# Use ActiveAdmin to edit a single record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have a model that needs editing that is associated with the current user called BillingProfile. How can I add a menu item that links to the edit page of the current user's BillingProfile? I don't want or need an index page for the BillingProfile as a user can only edit their own.

```
class User
  has_one :billing_profile
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Cancan to manage the ability to allow a User to edit his own Billing Profile.

ability.rb

```
...
cannot :edit_billing_profile, User do |u|
  u.user_id != user.id
end
...
```

admin/users.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  action_item :only => :show do
    link_to "Edit BP", edit_bp_path(user.id) if can? :edit_billing_profile, user
  end
end
```

Or you can try something like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "User" do
      f.input :name
    end
    f.inputs "Billing Profile" do
      f.has_one :billing_profile do |bp|
        w.input :address if can? :edit_billing_profile, bp.user
      end
    end
    f.buttons
  end
end
```

I have not test it, but I did something similar on a project.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you-

**Adding custom links:**

```
ActiveAdmin.register User, :name_space => :example_namespace do
  controller do
    private
    def current_menu
      item = ActiveAdmin::MenuItem.new :label => "Link Name", :url => 'http://google.com'
      ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[:example_namespace].menu.add(item)
      ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[:example_namespace].menu
    end
  end
end
```

I basically created a new ActiveAdmin::MenuItem and add it to the current ActiveAdmin menu with the namespace example_namespace and return the menu in the end of the current_menu method. Note: current_menu is a method expected by ActiveAdmin so don't change the name of it. You can add as many items you like and each of these items will be converted to a link on your navigation header. Note this works for ActiveAdmin version > 0.4.3 so you might need to do your own digging if you want to do it for version <= 0.4.3.

Comment: The issue isn't really getting the link in the menu, I think it's more only allowing the user to edit their own billing profile. It doesn't make sense to have an index page or even view the billing profile.

Answer (score 0):

I have a LinkHelper defined which has the following two methods:

```
#This will return an edit link for the specified object instance
def edit_path_for_object_instance(object_instance)
  model_name = object_instance.class.to_s.underscore
  path = send("edit_#{model_name}_path", object_instance)
end

#This will return an show link for the specified object instance
def show_path_for_object_instance(object_instance)
  model_name = object_instance.class.to_s.underscore
  path = send("#{model_name}_path", object_instance)
end
```

You can call the edit_path_for_object_instance method directly from your view and pass in the user.billing_profile object.

This will give you a link directly to the entity resulting a url like /billing_profile/ID/edit

An alternate approach is to use fields_for. This will allow you to create a form for the User attributes and update the associated BillingProfile at the same time. It would look something like this:

```
<%= form_for @user%>
  <%= fields_for @user.billing_profile do |billing_profile_fields| %>
    <%= billing_profile_fields.text_field :name %>    
  <% end %>
<%end%>
```

See here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Comment: I am working within ActiveAdmin though... I'm trying to figure out how to use their DSL to achieve something similar.